# Java: Jackson indentation adds a new map tag

Tags: java, json, indentation, jackson-databind

I'm using `jackson 2.9.8` and I'm trying to beutify my json.

The code I'm using is:

```
protected void setSuccessMessage(HttpServletResponse response, JSONObject jObj) throws IOException {
        // Set the status
        response.setStatus(200);
        // Create the response
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        jObj.put("success", 1);


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY);

        out.print(mapper.writeValueAsString(jObj));
        out.close();
    }
```

However, my output has a new `map` tag which I don't want. The output is:

```
{
  "map" : {
    "success" : 1,
    "documents_metata" : {
      "myArrayList" : [ {
        "map" : {
          "documentType" : "PS_XML",
          "patientId" : "x",
          "effectiveTime" : "2019-05-08",
          "author" : "xxx",
          "repositoryId" : "xxx",
          "id" : "xxx",
          "title" : "xxx"
        }
      }, {
        "map" : {
          "documentType" : "PS_PDF",
          "patientId" : "x",
          "effectiveTime" : "2019-05-08",
          "author" : "xxx",
          "repositoryId" : "xxx",
          "id" : "xxx",
          "title" : "xxx"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

The correct one should be:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "documents_metadata": [
        [
            {
                "documentType": "PS_PDF",
                "patientId": "x",
                "effectiveTime": "2019-05-08",
                "author": "xxx",
                "repositoryId": "xxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "title": "xxx"
            },
            {
                "documentType": "PS_XML",
                "patientId": "x",
                "effectiveTime": "2019-05-08",
                "author": "xxx",
                "repositoryId": "xxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "title": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The json without the `jackson` is fine but's it's not indented. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: JSONObject is from `org.json.simple.JSONObject` ?

Comment: @michalk from org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

Jackson doesn't know anything about `JSONObject` which comes from another library. So it's writing its internal structure like it would any other class. Use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org to tell Jackson how to treat it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsonorg.JsonOrgModule;

mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
```

Or use Jackson's own [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) (see e.g. [Working with Tree Model Nodes in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model) for a tutorial).

Comment: Or use a lava.lang.Map or your custom class. Jackson is designed to manipulate standard object and class without using low level implementation (JsonNode).